# Where does ft_get_option() get data from in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a recently acquired client's WordPress website and am having trouble finding where the values that are being populated from the function call ft_get_option() are coming from.

```
<?php echo stripslashes( ft_get_option('call_us') ); ?>
```

I tried navigating to /wp-admin/options.php and did not see anything there that said call_us, could it be from the theme they're using? Robust is the name of the theme, if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

That function it should be defined in `wp-content/themes/robust/functions.php`.

If is not in that file, search in each file from `wp-content/themes/robust` directory, or run a fgrep in you are on a linux machine:

```
cd wp-content/themes/robust && fgrep -rn 'ft_get_option' *
```

Comment: don't have access to a console on this server, and could not find it within that file. Will have to do some more digging

Comment: That theme includes some custom plugin(s) ? If so, you could search inside plugin(s) directories also. That code must be included in a theme or plugin file, because I searched in core WP code and does not exist.